# std::async, libc++ with clang33 does not work under Linux

Tags: linux, c++11, clang

I have a really simple program that works with clang33 under OSX. However if I try to run the same program under Linux it fails. Has anyone got std::asynch to work with clang33 under Linux (CentoOS)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    // future from a packaged_task
  std::packaged_task<int()> task([]() {
    return 7;
  });                                       // wrap the function
  std::future<int> f1 = task.get_future();  // get a future
  std::thread(std::move(task)).detach();    // launch on a thread

    // future from an async()
  std::future<int> f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, []() {
    return 8;
  });

  // future from a promise
  std::promise<int> p;
  std::future<int> f3 = p.get_future();
  std::thread([](std::promise<int> & p) {
    p.set_value(9);
  },
              std::ref(p)).detach();

  std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::flush;
  f1.wait();
  f2.wait();
  f3.wait();
  std::cout << "Done!\nResults are: " << f1.get() << ' ' << f2.get() << ' '
            << f3.get() << '\n';
}
```

The above example works with trunk/198686 when I compile libc++ with cxxabi. However now I have encountered another problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>  
#include <exception>

int main () {
  std::vector<int> foo;

  try {
    foo.at(1);
  }
  catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "exception caught: " << e.what() << '\n';
  }
  std::cout << "Works" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The example code above generates the following expected output under OS X:

exception caught: vector
Works

Under Linux I get the following output:

exception caught: Segmentation fault

I have debugged the code and segmentation fault occurs inside the destructor of logic_error (stdexcept.cpp, line 137). Does anyone have any suggestions?

BTW: Its no longer possible to compile libc++ using the libsupc++ method.

I have actually got everything to work. The above problems occurs with r198686. I checked out the same revision as @BenPope and then everything works as expected.

Thanks,
Patrik

Comment: It works for me.  My libc++ is built against libc++abi.  How did you build yours?  Hmm, actually, my libc++ is from the latest trunk, currently r197678.

Comment: I have now compiled libc++ using libc++abi and my example program now works as expected. My only worry is that I add to do a fix in cmath.h to compile libc++ (isnan was already defined). Thanks.

Comment: http://llvm.org/apt/ just use libc++ from the official apt repository. There are also prebuilt binaries available http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.4